# Flow for multiple asynchronous queries and running a callback when they complete

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a login form with Express.js.

```
var status = 0;
    req.assert('username', 'Username field is required').notEmpty();
    req.assert('password', 'Password field is required').notEmpty();
    if (req.validationErrors()) {
        res.render('login.html', {title: 'Login form', errors: req.validationErrors()});
    }
    db.query('SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = ? LIMIT 1', req.body.username, function(errs, data) {
        if (errs) {
            var errors = [{msg: 'Wrong password / username'}];
            res.render('login.html', {title: 'Login form', errors: errors});
        }
        if (data.length === 0) {
            var errors = [{msg: 'Wrong password / username'}];
            res.render('login.html', {title: 'Login form', errors: errors});
        }
        status++;
    });
    var sha1pw = libs.sha1Crypt(req.body.password);
    db.query('SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = ? LIMIT 1', sha1pw, function(errs, data) {
        if (errs) {
            var errors = [{msg: 'Wrong password / username'}];
            res.render('login.html', {title: 'Login form', errors: errors});
        }
        if (data.length === 0) {
            var errors = [{msg: 'Wrong password / username'}];
            res.render('login.html', {title: 'Login form', errors: errors});
        }
        status++;
    });

    if (status === 2) {
        res.send('works');
    }
```

If the user enters a invalid username they get redirected to login page with the errors. Now I don't how to structure it so that if both queries are successful (there's data, good user login) then it sends a message.  At the moment when the user enters a good password / username combination the page just keeps loading forever.

Comment: SHA1 is not secure, especially without salt.  Use PBKDFv2 or bcrypt.

Comment: `SELECT password FROM users WHERE password = ? LIMIT 1` — looks like a very bad idea

Answer (score 1):

With your current method, you would need to make your second query within the callback for the first:

```
db.query(sqlForUser, username, function () {
    db.query(sqlForPassword, password, function () {
        // res.render()
    }
}
```

The reason is that you're currently running these two queries simultaneously.

However, I would never suggest writing the code like this for this task.  Simply combine your queries into one:

```
db.query(
    'SELECT name FROM users WHERE name=? AND password=? LIMIT 1;', 
    [req.body.username, sha1pw], 
    function () {
        if (data.length) {
            // success!
        } else {
            // failure!
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: It is worth (I think) explicitly noting that not only are you (Alvaro) running the two queries simultaneously (which, ill advised as it is, you may be able to get away with) but you are then validating the results using the variable 'status' before the asynchronous queries complete. Brad's fixes your problem nicely, but I am adding this to emphasise that you need to keep the implications of asynchronous calls in mind, at all times.